# I can't see my D3.js design by open the HTML file

Tags: html, d3.js

I'm working on d3.js design.
I'm using the python server to see my design by browser.
the problem is I can't see my design by just open the HTML file .

thank you 
the index.html file

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <title>Flag example</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Custom styling -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>x

    <!-- Bootstrap grid setup -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="chart-area"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
<!-- External JS libraries -->
<script src="js/d3.min.js"></script>
<!-- Custom JS -->
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can You Please share your code

Comment: Okay, I shared the code, the index.html file

Comment: check this link => **https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/learn-d3-js-in-5-minutes-c5ec29fb0725/**